# Shallow copy of arrays for range loop in go

Tags: go, range, shallow-copy

The following code

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    type Recording struct {
        Heartbeat string   `json:"heartbeat"`
        Videos    []string `json:"videos,omitempty"`
    }

    recordings := []Recording{}
    recordings = append(recordings, Recording{Heartbeat: "Blue", Videos: []string{"Foo"}})

    for _, recording := range recordings {
        recording.Videos[0] = "Bar"
    }

    fmt.Println(recordings)
}
```

outputs

```
[{Blue [Bar]}]
```

and not

```
[{Blue [Foo]}]
```

This means that the array in the temporarily created recording object actually gets shallow-copied and modifies the original array, although that might not be programmer's intention. This can lead to unintended bugs.

Is there a way to do deep copy on a range loop for slices.

Comment: You do that manually if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because slices are pointers to underlying arrays, so you need to implement your own deep copy function if you need a separate copy of the data.

Here is your example updated to make a copy of `recordings`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    type Recording struct {
        Heartbeat string   `json:"heartbeat"`
        Videos    []string `json:"videos,omitempty"`
    }

    recordings := []Recording{}
    recordings = append(recordings, Recording{Heartbeat: "Blue", Videos: []string{"Foo"}})

    // Make a copy
    other := make([]Recording, len(recordings))
    for i, r := range recordings {
        other[i] = Recording{
            Heartbeat: r.Heartbeat,
            Videos:    append([]string{}, r.Videos...),
        }
    }

    for _, recording := range other {
        recording.Videos[0] = "Bar"
    }

    fmt.Println(recordings)
    fmt.Println(other)
}
```

Output:

```
[{Blue [Foo]}]
[{Blue [Bar]}]
```

Comment: Thanks - this is good and is guaranteed to work. However the extra syntax loses conciseness and a novice programmer can still run into issues. I guess this is somewhat of a language `gotya` that one has to be aware of

Comment: Yeah, Go is not known for its brevity.  I would just move that copy code into a `CopyRecordings` func, and then your main code can remain concise.  This also would make it easier to unit test the copy functionality independently of your other code.